# Symfony2 FOSUserBndle - adding new users with web form doesn't work

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have almost complete project. I've created it using XAMPP (Windows XP).

Finally I've set up Ubuntu server and moved my project to it.

Everything works fine except one. When I want to register new user using web form I get no errors, and user is not added to database (mysql).
I added new user with command line (fos:user:create) and it works.
When I log in with this user I can update its profile. It works.

The only thing that isn't working is registering new users with web form.

I've updated DG configuration in parameters.yml.

I use Symfony 2.3.1 on both XAMPP and Ubuntu Server. I use the same FOSUserBundle version.

Any ideas?

I've searched internet and nothing found.

Comment: Any errors in the apache logfile (usually `/var/log/apache2/error.log`)

Comment: I've checked. No errors. I've created new bundle and added FOSUserBundle. In new bundle everything works fine.